# What could be causing the Django session to not properly store previous values when handling requests from Angular for view counts on blog posts?

Tags: django, angular, api, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

**The Django session is not fetching the previously stored value by the angular GET request.**

I try to do a view count on blog posts. but one user gives only one view count.

in the `views.py` file

```
def get(self, request, id=None):
        obj = Model.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(obj)
        session = SessionStore(request.session.session_key)
        viewed_objs = session.get('viewed_objs', [])
        if id not in viewed_objs:
            obj.view_count = obj.view_count + 1
            obj.save()
            viewed_objs.append(id)
            session['viewed_objs'] = viewed_objs
            session.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            serialized_data = serializer.data
            serialized_data['message'] = 'View count not updated. Object already viewed by this user.'
            return Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This code works properly if I send the request by Postman. when i same request by angular that time every time I add the view count of the same user.

*problem is angular sends a request to the Django backend that time Django session does not work correctly*.

In the `settings.py` file

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:4200'
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True    

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
]
```

I do all of them still I am not gating previous store value in the angular request

*`I think that angular makes a problem for the Django session`*